# Distance between elements in Hamel Basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I was proving the theorem that if dual of X is separable then X is separable itself. 
The proof lead me to show that Hamel Basis for X should be countable. So what I was trying to do is to assume that Hamel Basis $H$ is not countable and produce linear functionals $f_x$ on H so that they will go to $1$ on just one element $x\in H$ and to $0$ for the rest. I know the theorem that we can produce functionals sending one vector to any number and given **closed** subspace to zero. But here I can't show that vector space generated by $H\setminus {x}$ is closed, or that $x$ is not in there. Is this true that there is no  $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$ for $x_n\in H\setminus {x}$ in general Banach Space. Does anybody know how to finish my proof: meaning to construct uncountable number of "discrete" functionals on $H$? I know there is a proof in Reed and Simon but I am trying to finish mine.

Comment: $C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ with the topology of uniform convenge is separable, but any Hamel Basis for $C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ is uncountable.

Comment: For any Banach space, the Hamel Basis is either finite or uncountable.

Comment: @SoumyaSinhaBabu You are right. In fact, your statement can be easily proved using Baire Category Theorem.

Comment: Exactly @Ramiro.

Comment: @Ramiro & @ SoumyaSinhaBabu Thank you all! My approach doesn't work unfortunately.